# How do I print to cosole from views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-views, console.log

I'm using django/python and want to print the value of the variables I'm using.
'Print vairableName' and 'console.log(variableName)' don't work.
What is the easiest way to view the contents of a variable in the views.py file?

```
poBox = request.POST.get("poBox","")
print poBox
```

Nothing shows up.  Please help.
I want to view the contents of poBox.

Comment: Well, it's possible that your `poBox` is just empty string, so `print ''` wouldn't show anything. You need to add something more obvious like `print 'poBox is %s' % poBox`.

Comment: `poBox = request.POST.get("poBox","")` sets the variable `poBox` to an empty string if the key `'poBox'` doesn't exist in the `request.POST` dictionary, so you are probably just printing an empty string

Comment: Using a more developed development environment will help you *much* more than a console ever would

Comment: how are you sending the data into the view ? Also, what do you get if you do `print request.POST.copy()` ?

Comment: poBox is not empty.  That item actually works with data.  I was just using it as an example.  I'm passing the data into the view using...                       <form name="myForm" action="../../myOtherPage/" method="post">

Comment: So, yeah.  Turns out 'print variableName' does work.  I was looking for the printout in the console.  The data was being printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb)? It's a very nice debugger, with which, after installing, all you need to do is write `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` right before the line(s) you want to inspect (like adding a breakpoint), and it will pause the execution when the code gets to that line, allowing you to type python instructions into the server's terminal, such as `print <variable_name>`.

While in the console, you can type in `s` to step into the next step, `n` to go to the next instruction and `c` to continue running the code up until the next breakpoint.

Just remember to remove that line after using it, so your code can run normally.